# Висячий дефис или многоточие? Думаю, если бы в моих архивах нашлись антикварные дагерротипы с изображениями прапрапра-, то их счастье

Tags: орфография, дефис

[текст о фотографиях дедов, бабушек, прадедов, прабабушек] *Думаю, если бы в моих архивах нашлись антикварные дагерротипы с изображениями **прапрапра-**, то их счастье также выглядело бы...*

- Можно ли оставить висячий дефис, если нет второй части сложного слова?

Comment: Век дагерротипа был краток и так давно, что любой из сохранившихся есть ценность историческая, но не всегда антикварная. Ведь когда он (в моих архивах) хранит образ собственных предков, и не идёт речь о передаче его или продаже, тогда не применимо понятие «антиквариат». Можно определить дагерротип старинным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы поставил многоточие:

> Он прошел под ивами, высматривая у воды плоский камень (их оказалось два, белых и плоских, составивших один), где его прабабка, и прапрабабка, и прапра… полоскали белье, женская доля, вереница сцепленных женских ликов, рожавших, и рожавших, и вновь рожавших. [Владимир Маканин. Утрата (1984)]
>
> Слишком многие из нас еще могут сказать: «Это сделал мой прапра…» . [Евгения Озерова. Сказки атомного века (2002)]

Или ничего:

> Смотрю на автопортрет моего прапра на стене. [Эдвард Радзинский. Наш Декамерон (1980-1990)]